# LinkedHashSet returns as HashSet in Low level datastore fetch Java

Tags: java, jdo, linkedhashset

The parameter is declared as follows,

```
@Persistent private Set<ScopeType> scope = new LinkedHashSet<ScopeType>();
```

While fetching with High-level datastore fetch, it responds with **LinkedHashSet**, but on Low-level fetch the response is a **HashSet**, Is this something expected?

Answer (score 0):

That looks reasonable.  The type of `scope` is `Set`, not `LinkedHashSet` nor `HashSet`.  Those are implementation types.  Any user of `scope` is only guaranteed that the declared type is satisfied, not that a particular implementation is in use.

If the order-preserving feature of `LinkedHashSet` must be maintained, then `scope` must be declared as `LinkedHashSet`.

Using a concrete type as a declared type breaks most style rules, but is in this case unavoidable.  There is no interface similar to `Set` which is available to be used.  That is a consequence of limitations of java's typing.